# Artifacts appear on dynamically generated & animated canvas image on iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, canvas

I am making an HTML5 web app for WeChat (iOS and Android alike), using pure JavaScript (no jQuery or any other third-party library). I'm generating an artistic-looking animation on the screen, based on what image elements user selects. JS draws into canvas every single frame, and that works surprisingly well (fps on iPhone 5 is between 50 and 60, Nexus 4 is stuck at 60fps).

Elements are drawn using Canvas2D transformation. Unfortunately due to some IP rights issues, i cannot post exact code here, so I am providing a bit stripped-off version:

Canvas init:

```
app.init = function()
{
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.ctx.canvas.width = 800;
    this.ctx.canvas.height = 800;
}
```

Image elements used for drawing:

```
app.onResourcesLoaded = function()
{
    this.elements = new Array();
    this.elements.push( this.getImageByID("blue") );
    this.elements.push( this.getImageByID("green") );
    this.elements.push( this.getImageByID("red") );
    this.elements.push( this.getImageByID("yellow") );
    this.elemnum = this.elements.length;
}
app.getImageByID = function(id)
{
    // looks up into loaded images, find the one with provided id
    // and returns image object, or null if none found.
    // If found, returned value is object of following structure:
    var foundImage = {
        image: imageObject, 
        position: { x:0.0, y:0.0 },
        rotation: 0.0,
        scale: 1.0,
        center: { x:0.5*imageObject.width, y:0.5*imageObject.height }
    };
    return foundImage;
}
```

Canvas drawing:

```
// This function is executed using requestAnimationFrame or setInterval (if requestAnimationFrame is not available)
app.drawImage = function()
{
    var elapsedTime = this.calcElapsedTime(); // returns time between this and previous frame
    this.animateElementsTransformation( elapsedTime ); // goes through each of elements and updated position, rotation and scale data.

    // draws first background image as base
    this.ctx.drawImage( backgroundImage, 0, 0);
    for( var i = 0; i<this.elemnum; i++)
    {
        var e = this.elements[i];
        this.ctx.save();
        {
            this.ctx.translate( e.position.x, e.position.y );
            this.ctx.rotate( e.angle );
            this.ctx.scale( e.scale, e.scale );
            this.ctx.drawImage( e.image, -e.center.x, -e.center.y );
        }
        this.ctx.restore();
    }
}
```

On Android and iOS alike all works great with great performance. However, on iOS, in WeChat or in stand-alone Safari, occasionally (eg. once i few seconds) I can see some black straight lines, about 1px wide, that appear over entire screen (like from one edge to another). I have checked and these lines are in no way related to position/orientation/scale of the elements. They appear somewhat always on same spot, as if entire canvas is actually made of some triangles and browser has trouble refreshing them. They are not very obvious, and appear only once in few seconds.

Has anyone encountered this before? Is it a bug in Safari, maybe GPU driver bug? Or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Why would someone down-vote this question without at least leaving explanation why and what I should do to improve it? I am really open to change the form of the question, or add more details if needed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure it out:

I have "scroll" background which is made by drawing one image twice, offset-ed by width of drawn image. Since I use translate, and translation increment is not whole value but a floating point, because of image filtering, sometimes, a background would be visible at the connecting edge between two drawn images - only on iOS Safari, while on Android Chrome did not have this issue.

I have solved it by doing translate to rounded values. In case anyone runs into same trouble :-)